# What is the difference between application.yml and secrets.yml in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. When installing `Figaro gem`, an `application.yml` is automatically created. And inside this file I planned on storing login credentials for SendGrid.
2. But by default in the rails application, there is another `secrets.yml` file, with the secret_key_base.

I'm little confused on their relationship.

**My question**: Is it necessary to have both? Can I combine them? Should both be added to `gitignore` ?

Comment: Th info which you need is already listed in the figaro git repo itself. Take a look here https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#is-applicationyml-like-secretsyml

Comment: That was very helpful. One thing I still don't understand is if `secret_key_base` should be moved to `application.yml` or if should be left in `secrets.yml`, and both files used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it there as it is, just put the new variables to the `application.yml` and make sure you `gitignore` both files since you need those only for localhost. For production you have to put the keys to a different place based on the service. I'm using heroku and have to save production variables from terminal.